# Batch install to specific location

Tags: batch-file, cmd, installshield

I was having trouble after creating a windows service in c# with creating a silent install with a batch file or w.e. is needed that takes in just the location of the install, as when I run setup.exe or the msi file that is all that's in there. It will prompt to change location if desired, otherwise go to default C:\drive folder that is preset within the service, no other options are required.

I was wondering how to use a iss file or an answer file to create either a cmd prompt or script to mass install on many computers easily.

Currently setup.exe accepts in the cmd setup.exe /quiet instead of what I have been seeing -s or /s which also had caused some confusion and to why I was looking for help. Thank you.

Comment: You question is difficult to understand.  How many questions are you asking?  For the location you can pass something like this to the .msi file....  INSTALLDIR="%InstallDir%\"     Assuming you have set the Variable InstallDir to the desired location.

Comment: Yes I mean I am not trying to ask more than one question just for the best solution, I did the installdir and targetdir but it doesn't install my service properly and start it like it should, it just loads the files into that location.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I typically use InstallShield for that.  If you are doing this in pure batch, then you will need to take steps to configure/start the service.  See SC /?.  That will allow you to query the service, stop, start, etc.  Give it a try and reply with more specifics if needed.